# Compilation of same Java Files

Tags: java, compilation, jvm

Can 2 same java file complied from different system but both of them having same
Operating system(Windows 7), will generate different .class file(in Size)?

Comment: yes, it depends on JVM version, according to JVM different bytecode will be generated, IDE also generates different.

Comment: I believe it is actually dependent on the JDK, not JVM.

Comment: Different JDKs versions can produce class files which slightly different sizes.

Comment: If size differs will it affect the functionality, if both java files are same?

Comment: Even compiling the same source file on the same machine with the same JDK may produce different class files, depending on how the compiler has been implemented. There’s a bunch of things which don’t affect the semantics of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check if there are different versions of the JDK (Java Development Kit) used to compile your code and the .class file version (differs from java versions)

You can check differences using the javap utility:

```
javap -verbose path/to/ClassFile.class
```

and compare output of each class